# DateTime Object Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on
>   boolean in /homepages/21/*****/*****/******/card/upload.php:29 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/21/******/*****/*****/card/upload.php on line 29

```
$newarray['date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("j M Y", $arry[0])->format("Y-m-d");
```

How can fix this problem?

Comment: what is there in `$arry[0]`?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure. If it is failing false is a boolean hence the error.

Comment: also the format should have dashes `'j-M-Y'`

Comment: Here is the manual btw http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you are passing an invalid date expression via `$arry[0]`.

Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcfac18182b54b50d1fd236d3334ca6b2ba98057):

```
// it works when $arry[0] is valid
$arry=['28 Jan 2017'];
$newarray['date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("j M Y", $arry[0])->format("Y-m-d");
echo $newarray['date'];

echo "\n\n";

// it doesn't otherwise
$arry=['28 Mon 2017'];  // or an empty string, etc.
$newarray['date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("j M Y", $arry[0])->format("Y-m-d");
echo $newarray['date'];
```

Output:

```
2017-01-28

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in [...][...]:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```